# Macbook and iMac Assignment Operator (<-) Shortcut (Option with -) Not Working in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, variable-assignment, operator-keyword, assignment-operator

"-" with the "option"  key (refers ALT key)  had been used as the assignment operator. Since RStudio became POSIT the combination of these buttons not just working in RStudio. But it works in R. When you press this key combination together, a vertical line "|" coming out. Even though I changed the "insert assignment operator" from "Modify Keyboard Shortcuts" in the global options, this vertical mark continues to appear. I guess these key combinations get in front of the assignment operator shortcut in the macOS and don't allow it to work. Any ideas on how I can fix it?